# SVG symbols for water management

Tags: qgis, symbology, mapinfo, svg, water

I'm searching for SVG of different (german) hydrant types ("Unterflurhydrant", "Überflurhydrant", "Hydrantenschacht") etc.

The symbols are currently stored as polygons in MapInfo's proprietary .TAB (the equivalent of .shp) format. You specify the tab, tell which feature you want as symbol and voila - that symbol is used for all hydrants of type xy, stored as polygons.

I have now to setup our look'n'feel in QGIS. So I need our polygon-symbols as SVG OR I get the symbols as SVG from somewhere.

I need to use them for visualization purposes in QGIS. Any possible/suggested data sources?

Comment: Have you seen these symbols used somewhere before? If you regional water service has a web map then you may be able to ask them to provide these symbols to you?

Comment: well, we use them in our GIS - but we created polygons and use them as symbols (MapInfo). I have now to setup our look'n'feel in QGIS. So i need our polygon-symbols as SVG OR i get the symbols as SVG from somewhere.

Comment: you can try to make them by yourself, you only need a vector draw program like inkscape: https://inkscape.org/de/

Comment: yeah i tried that but my inkscape/drawing skills are too poor!

Comment: How many symbols are there? What format are they current stored in for use in MapInfo?

Comment: around 8 for now. The format MapInfo uses is just a polygon - saved in their proprietary .TAB (the equivalent of .shp) format. you specify the tab, tell which feature you want as symbol and voila - that symbol is used for all hydrants of type xy. neat as long as you stay with MapInfo, sucks if you want to change..

Comment: I edited your question to incorporate some essential information you only provided in the comments section, but you may want to post a separate question. Please use the [edit] link to continue improving the question (this makes it much more likely that someone answers it). At this point it's edging towards being two separate questions: (1) Where to find SVG images of german hydrants? and (2) How to convert symbols from MapInfo proprietary format to SVG.

Comment: Sorry, dont have an actual answer, but you could give "tracing bitmap" in Inkscape a try: https://inkscape.org/doc/tutorials/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html